# test / mocking for a UIAlertView called as class method from inside of method on view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, ocmock

I'm writing tests for a performLogin method from within a view controller and I can't refactor the original method, nor any other files in the project.  I can only modify my LoginTest.m file.  I am trying to use OCMock to accomplish this testing without changing the original program files.

I am trying to verify that a UIAlertView is shown if the performLogin method receives a exception.  The ViewHelper class has one class method that returns void and creates and shows a UIAlertView.

I have mocked the view controller that calls the ViewHelper and I have tried to used OCMock to test for UIAlertView class using examples from various searches, however those tests are failing as it is not catching the creating of the AlertView.

I'm new using OCMock and I'm not sure how to mock the ViewHelper file for this type of test, especially as it's called from within a method and not anchored to a property.

There is probably an easy way to do this, but I have not figure it out and any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Inside of the method when doLogin is called, it returns TRUE or throws an exception.  When the exception is throw, it should pop up a UIAlertView with a message.  I want to test this section of the code and verify that the UIAlertView is actually shown.

Note that ViewHelper is called directly from within the catch block.

the method looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender {
  if(valid) 
  {
    @try
    {
      //loginModel is a private instance variable
      loginModel = [[Services sharedInstance] getLoginModel];
      [loginModel doLoginWithUsername:username andPassword:password];
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showWelcomeScreen" sender:self];
    }
    @catch(NSException *e)
    {

      //I NEED TO TEST THAT THIS CALL OCCURS AND THE UIAlertView is shown
      //Not sure how to do this as it's not anchored to a property or method
      //and is called as a class method

      [ViewHelper showAlertForTitle:"Error" andTheMessage:@"network error"
        andAccessibilityLabel:@"Network Error"];
    }
   }
}
```

the ViewHelpder.m looks like this - Note, its a class method:

```
+(void) showAlertForTitle:(NSString *)title andTheMessage:(NSString *)message      andAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label
{
    NSLog(@"reached alert notification class");
    UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title  message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [successAlert setAccessibilityLabel:label];
    [successAlert show];
}
```

Among other things is what I've tried so far:

```
- (void)testForfailedLogin {

    //call singleton first to initialize mocked login model
    [[Services sharedInstance] getLoginModel];

    id mockAlertView = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UIAlertView class]];
    [[[mockAlertView stub] andReturn:mockAlertView] alloc];
    (void)[[[mockAlertView expect] andReturn:mockAlertView]
       initWithTitle:OCMOCK_ANY
       message:OCMOCK_ANY
       delegate:OCMOCK_ANY
       cancelButtonTitle:OCMOCK_ANY
       otherButtonTitles:OCMOCK_ANY, nil];
    [[mockAlertView expect] show];


    //set the actual IBOutlets with login values designed to sucessfully login
    self.controller.usernameTextField.text = @"error";
    self.controller.passwordTextField.text = @"error";

    //call the login process to verify the login method
    [self.controller performLogin:nil];

    [mockAlertView verify];
    [mockAlertView stopMocking];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember OCMock apis already so surely this will not compile but the idea is correct I believe. (I am basically following [this guide](http://ocmock.org/reference/#stubing-methods))

First, it is better to test this with two tests.
The first test will check only that `[ViewHelper showAlertForTitle:"Error"  andTheMessage:@"network error" andAccessibilityLabel:@"Network Error"]` is called at the exception time. The second test will check an alert view appears  (or whatever other thing you want expect to happen) when `+[ViewHelper showAlertForTitle:andTheMessage:andAccessibilityLabel:]` is called.

The (important parts of the) first test:

```
// ① You need to setup something to raise an exception
// so the catch block will be called
// Probably you want to use [OCMArg any] or [OCMArg anyPointer]
OCMStub([mockServices loginWithUsername:[OCMArg isNotNil]
                            andPassword:[OCMArg isNotNil]])
  .andThrow(anException);

// ② Call your method
// sender can be nil in your code.
[controller performLogin:sender]; 

// ③ Expect your method to be called
OCMExpect([mockViewHelper showAlertForTitle:"Error" 
                              andTheMessage:@"network error"
                      andAccessibilityLabel:@"Network Error"]);

// ④ Verify
OCMVerifyAll(mockViewHelper)
```

The gist of the second test:

```
// ① Stub everything you want to check to be called inside 
// `+[ViewHelper showAlertForTitle:andTheMessage:andAccessibilityLabel:]`
// probably your UIAlertView, etc
id mockAlertView = ...

// ② Call your method
[ViewHelper showAlertForTitle:@"something" 
                andTheMessage:@"something" 
        andAccessibilityLabel:@"something"]; 

// ③ Expect your stuff to be called
OCMExpect([mockAlertView someMethod]);

// ④ Verify
OCMVerifyAll(mockAlertView)
```

One last thing, in the objc world Exceptions are used for programmer errors, if you are designing those classes consider to return an NSError like many other Cocoa APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it triggered what I needed to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the answer by nacho4d, there are two parts to this: making the login model throw an exception and verifying that the controller shows the error.

Given the constraints you describe I'd use a partial mock for the login model to throw the exception:

```
id modelMock = OCMPartialMock([[Services sharedInstance] getLoginModel]);
OCMStub([modelMock doLoginWithUsername:[OCMArg any] andPassword:[OCMArg any]])
   .andThrow([NSException exceptionWithName:@"TestException" reason:@"Test" userInfo:nil]);
```

To check that the panel is shown I wouldn't bother with the view. I'd simply check that the class method in the helper was called from the `performLogin:` implementation:

```
id viewHelperMock = OCMClassMock([ViewHelper class]);
[controller performLogin:sender]; 
OCMVerify([viewHelperMock showAlertForTitle:"Error" andTheMessage:@"network error" andAccessibilityLabel:@"Network Error"]);
```

Comment: thank you.  My issue initially was that I had the exception setup fine, but I forgot about a username/password validation check that wrapped the doLogin call.  I had to do a partialMock and stub out that call to always return true, to allow the doLogin to be called.  Once there I was able to fine tune the return of either a true value or an Exception.

Comment: It is so nice to have advice directly from the creator of OCMock :)